# SocketError (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known): Rails Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

My action mailer configuratin is:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 address: 'smtp.mycustumdomail.com',
 port: 587,
 domain: 'mycustomdomain.com',
 user_name: 'memories@mycustomdomain.com',
 password: 'mypassword',
 authentication: 'plain',
 enable_starttls_auto: true 
}
```

For the above configuration I am getting following error:

> [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [14a369d5-5a2c-44fd-bb4b-2c5a5edf90a6] Error performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 14a369d5-5a2c-44fd-bb4b-2c5a5edf90a6) from Async(mailers) in 78.46ms: SocketError (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known):

I have purchased the domain from Godaddy. And configure its mail to gmail gsuite.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem, and solved it by change the smtp settings.

Thank you zakariah1!

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from the Rails docs.  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

This is from the Rails docs for setting up gmail.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail

Should your address be the following?
     :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'example.com' }
```

Comment: @zakariaj1 Still the problem remains same.